# Arraylist.add method showing java heap space exception

Tags: java, heap-memory

I m reading the content from file and then adding some word from readed string into my arraylist.it is working for small size of text file but not for large file having 20kb size.what is the problem??

Comment: Please add your code so the problem can be examined
this may happen because of a memory leak.. [this](http://blogs.opcodesolutions.com/roller/java/entry/solve_java_lang_outofmemoryerror_java) may help you

Comment: Current heap size is not sufficient. try increasing the heap space for the program using -Xms and  -Xmx

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store more information in memory you must increase the heap space

```
-Xms<size>        set initial Java heap size
-Xmx<size>        set maximum Java heap size
-Xss<size>        set java thread stack size
```

For example if you want to give your Java program needs a 64Mb initial and 256Mb maximum heap size you could launch it as follows:

```
java -Xms64m -Xmx256m
```

Comment: It seems unlikely that you'd need to increase the memory of a (presumably) simple program using a 20kb file.

Comment: It depends on how much memory installed on his machine, or the version of the jdk, etc... But yes you're right it seems unlikely indeed. But without more information (i.e. the source code for instance) I can't say for sure.